# I used url string but it's not display image url(undefined) in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import './Collection-items.styles.scss';


const CollectionItems = ({id, name, price, imageurl}) => (
    <div className='collection-item'>
        <div className='image' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageurl})`
    }}>

        
        <div className='collection-footer'>
        <span className='name'>{ name }</span>
        <span className='price'>{ price }</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
);
export default CollectionItems;
```

Comment: can you check if url is getting any value ?

Comment: for what type value bro

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.